# Why is `sudo cat /tmp/1 > file` wrong?

Tags: bash, cat

I do `sudo cat /tmp/1 > /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules` but I get

```
bash: /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules: Permission denied
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04
Linux kernel: 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirections are set up by the current shell, so `sudo` has no effect on your ability to write in `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

The usual trick for this is to use `tee`:

```
sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules < /tmp/1
```

As pointed out by [infixed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/162020/infixed) though, in this particular case you don't need a redirection:

```
sudo cp /tmp/1 /etc/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules
```

Comment: I get the output to STOUT when doing this. Is it the purpose?

Comment: Yes, `tee` outputs to the file given as its parameter, and to standard output. You can redirect the output to `/dev/null` if you don't want to see it!

Comment: Redirect STDOUT to /dev/null if you do not wish to see the output

Comment: "tee" is useful if you want to append to a file; e.g. "tee -a /protected/file"